# Let stay thread running on form close

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I made a syncing thread on my application and I want to know is there a way to let the thread stay open until it finishes it's syncing process, if i close the application form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the commentary to Rob's excellent answer, the question of showing UI whilst waiting was raised. If you need to show UI whilst waiting, then you will need a more advanced wait that `TThread.WaitFor`. This is what I use in its place, relying on [`MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684242%28VS.85%29.aspx).

```
procedure WaitUntilSignaled(Handle: THandle; ProcessMessages: Boolean);
begin
  if ProcessMessages then begin
    Application.ProcessMessages;//in case there are any messages are already waiting in the queue
    while MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, Handle, False, INFINITE, QS_ALLEVENTS)=WAIT_OBJECT_0+1 do begin
      Application.ProcessMessages;
    end;
  end else begin
    WaitForSingleObject(Handle, INFINITE);
  end;
end;

....

Form.Show;
WaitUntilSignaled(Thread.Handle, True);
Form.Close;
```

Comment: That's working!! Great! But one problem more. If I show the form with showmodal. Then application will not close. How can I close it then?

Comment: @evilone You can't do what I'm suggesting with ShowModal because that runs its own message loop. I think you should be using plain Show but not allowing the user any way to close the form apart from, perhaps, an abort button that would need cooperation from the thread. You probably don't want to do this. If you used ShowModal you'd have to ditch the MsgWaitForMultipleObjects and instead get the thread to signal to the modal form to close when it was done.

Comment: @evilone If you have any problems with this then I think it now warrants a new question.

Answer (score 6):

Call the thread's `WaitFor` method in your DPR file, after the `Application.Run` line. If the thread has already finished running, then `WaitFor` will return immediately. Otherwise, it will pause the main thread until the other thread terminates. (You'll have to make sure the variable still refers to a valid `TThread` instance, so don't set its `FreeOnTerminate` property.)

There are additional things you may wish to consider, beyond the simple issue of allowing the thread to continue running:

- Programs only have limited time to stop running if the OS is shutting down or the user is logging out, so you might not have time to wait for synchronization to finish before the OS kills your program.
- Users might wonder why the program is still running even though they told it to close, so consider showing some UI while synchronization continues.
- Users might not care about synchronization if they're in a hurry and need the program to stop running immediately, so in that UI, you may wish to offer an "abort sync" command.

Comment: Thanks, I think I can add some UI on that thingy!

Comment: But how can I show some UI to user while Thread.WaitFor. It's returning Cardinal type, is it possible to do something with that?

Comment: @evilone if you need some UI then you'll need MsgWaitForMultipleObjects rather than WaitFor. That will allow you to pump messages in the main thread to keep the UI alive whilst the other thread completes.

Comment: @David I'm new to Delphi, so where I must call this MsgWaitForMultipleObjects and what I must set for parameters. Really don't get it right now.

Comment: @evilone for this to be effective you need to have some UI ideas. What will your UI show? How will the thread report progress? Can the user abort sync?

Comment: @David I think for start I only show the splash screen with information that syncing in progress...

Comment: @evilone since I need to show some code, I added another answer to demonstrate how MsgWaitForMultipleObjects can be used.