# Delphi: ShellExecuteEx to .txt file

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I want to compile a Delphi program from another delphi program, to do this I use ShellExecuteEx so that the program waits until the compiling is done.
This works fine but I want the .cmd output in a .txt file, this isnt working properly.

```
    StartAndWait('cmd', '/c  c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild xyz.dproj /t:Build /p:Config=release >> log.txt');
```

StartAndWait starts the function with ShellExecuteEx and waits until the program is    finished,

```
IF ShellExecuteEx(@SEInfo) THEN
BEGIN
  REPEAT
    Application.ProcessMessages;
    // Damit die Prozessorauslastung sinkt :-)
    Sleep(100);
    GetExitCodeProcess(SEInfo.hProcess, ExitCode);
  UNTIL (ExitCode <> STILL_ACTIVE) OR Application.Terminated;
  Result := True;
END;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you specify how this fails. Also, It would be much better to write the wait without the `Sleep`. You need `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`. Or the lazy way of running the shell execute and the wait out of a background thread. That way you can use `WaitForSingleObject` and not block the UI. Personally if I were you I would drop `cmd`, and drop `>>` and use `CreateProcess` with a pipe to read the `stdout` of the other process.

Comment: It doesnt really fail, the .txt just stays empty.
Do you have an example how to read the stdout with a pipe?

Comment: Would you prefer to do it that way rather than writing to file?

Comment: I doesn't really matter how it's done as long as the compiling output can be found in a txt file.

Comment: OK, you'd rather it landed in a file. That's easy to achieve. And you want to append content `>>` rather than clear the file `>`?

Comment: maybe you can have http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JCL_Help:CreateDOSProcessRedirected@string@string@string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally think it is easier to do this with a call to `CreateProcess`. You need to create a file handle, and pass that to `CreateProcess` to use as stdout. There are a few details that you need to take care over, mostly concerning handle inheritance. You can get it all done with this function:

```
procedure ExecuteCommandAndAppendToFile(
  const Executable: string;
  const Arguments: string;
  const WorkingDir: string;
  const OutputFile: string
);
const
  sa: TSecurityAttributes = (nLength: SizeOf(sa); bInheritHandle: True);
var
  hstdout: THandle;
  StartupInfo: TStartupInfo;
  ProcessInfo: TProcessInformation;
  cmd: string;
begin
  hstdout := CreateFile(PChar(OutputFile), GENERIC_WRITE, 0, @sa, OPEN_ALWAYS, 
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
  Win32Check(hstdout<>INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
  try
    //move to end of file since we wish to append
    SetFilePointer(hstdout, 0, nil, FILE_END);

    ZeroMemory(@StartupInfo, SizeOf(StartupInfo));
    StartupInfo.cb := SizeOf(StartupInfo);
    StartupInfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW or STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    StartupInfo.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;
    StartupInfo.hStdOutput := hstdout;
    StartupInfo.hStdError := hstdout;

    cmd := Executable + ' ' + Arguments;
    UniqueString(cmd);//not needed but let's be explicit
    if not CreateProcess(nil, PChar(cmd), nil, nil, True,
      CREATE_NO_WINDOW or NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, PChar(WorkingDir),
      StartupInfo, ProcessInfo) then
    begin
      RaiseLastOSError;
    end;
    try
      WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
    finally
      CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);
      CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(hstdout);
  end;
end;
```

This uses `WaitForSingleObject` to wait for completion. That will block the thread that runs this code. You could move this code into a different thread if you have GUI that you wish not to block. Or you could use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`. Or you could use your `Sleep` based loop if you must (I don't much care for `Sleep` but it's your choice).

So, you may wish to tweak bits of this, but the basics are all present here.

Comment: **Note**: Checking errors from `SetFilePointer` is a pain in the backside. So I just skipped it. In my own code I'd call `SetFilePointerEx` which makes error checking easier. But `SetFilePointerEx` does not exist on Win2k. If anyone uses this code, that issue should be addressed.

Comment: Good. If you want to use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`, you can use the code from my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334553/processmessages-and-use-of-application/10341681#10341681  or here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871358/let-stay-thread-running-on-form-close